# How to do Jest testing for form validation errors?

Tags: reactjs, validation, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test a login form validation errors:

```
<Form className='form' onSubmit={onSubmit} data-testid='form'>
<FormGroup className='form-group'>
      <input
        type='email'
        placeholder='Email Address'
        name='email'
        value={email}
        onChange={onChange}
        required
      />
    </FormGroup>
    <FormGroup className='form-group'>
      <input
        type='password'
        placeholder='Password'
        name='password'
        value={password}
        onChange={onChange}
        minLength='6'
      />
    </FormGroup>
    <input type='submit' value='Login' />
  </Form>
```

but the problem is i am unable to get the error text in the
component = render()

my test is as follows:

```
it('validate user inputs, and provides error messages', async () => {
    const { getByTestId, getByText, getByPlaceholderText } = component
    
    fireEvent.change(screen.queryByPlaceholderText(/Email Address/i), {
        target: {value: ""},
    });

    fireEvent.change(screen.queryByPlaceholderText(/Password/i), {
        target: {value: ""},
    });

    fireEvent.submit(getByTestId("form"));

    expect(getByText("Please fill out this field.")).toBeInTheDocument();


})
```

I am using react testing library with jest

Comment: Could you share your `onSubmit` function and the JSX for rendering the error message? It's hard to say what might be going wrong without seeing how the message is supposed to appear.

Comment: this is the problem. jsx does not have these error messages. I thinks its html5 form validation that is being done in browser. my function is:
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    login(email, password);
  };

Comment: Which form library are you using?  Bootstrap?

Comment: no Im not using any library its html form validation.
I also have checked the dom output in test runner it does not show the validation error

Answer (score 1):

The text displayed on submit is drawn by the browser, not by DOM, so it cannot be inspected with JavaScript.

You may need to add a JavaScript handler for that to sync the actual text to the DOM.

```
const [errorText, setErrotText] = React.useState("");

const handleInvalid = () => {
  setErrorText("Please fill out this field.");
};

const handleValid = () => {
  setErrorText("");
};

return (
  <input onInvalid={handleInvalid} onValid={handleValid} />
);
```

Or, you can check the detailed error type by inspecting the [`ValidityState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) by accessing `element.validity` of the input element.

DOM validation is accessible regardless of the testing framework or forms library you use.

For example:

```
expect(getByPlaceholder("Password").validity.tooShort).toBe(false);
```